# Repeat a record for N times and create a new sequence from 1 to N

Tags: r

I want to repeat the rows of a data.frame for N times. Here N calculates based on the difference between the values of a first and second column in each row of a data.frame. Here I am facing a problem with N. In particular, N may change per each row. And I need to create a new column by creating a sequence from a first value to second value in row 1 by increasing K. Here K remains constant for all the rows.

```
Ex: d1<-data.frame(A=c(2,4,6,8,1),B=c(8,6,7,8,10))
```

In the above dataset, there are 5 rows. THe difference between first and second values in first row is 7. Now I need to replicate the first row for 7 times and need to create a new column with the sequence of 2,3,4,5,6,7 and 8.

I can create a dataset by using the following code.

```
dist<-1
rec_len<-c()
seqe<-c()
for(i in 1:nrow(d1))
{
    a<-seq(d1[i,"A"],d1[i,"B"],by=dist)
    rec_len<-c(rec_len,length(a))
    seqe<-c(seqe,a)
}
d1$C<-rec_len

d1<-d1[rep(1:nrow(d1),d1$C),]
d1$D<-seqe
row.names(d1)<-NULL
```

But it is taking very long time. Is there any possibity to speed up the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.table` approach for this can be to use `1:nrow(df)` as grouping variable to make rowwise operation for creating a list with the sequences of A and B, and then unlist, i.e.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(d1)[, C := B - A + 1][, 
     D := list(list(seq(A, B))), by = 1:nrow(d1)][, 
                lapply(.SD, unlist), by = 1:nrow(d1)][, 
                                              nrow := NULL][]
```

Which gives,

> ```
>    A  B  C  D
>  1: 2  8  7  2
>  2: 2  8  7  3
>  3: 2  8  7  4
>  4: 2  8  7  5
>  5: 2  8  7  6
>  6: 2  8  7  7
>  7: 2  8  7  8
>  8: 4  6  3  4
>  9: 4  6  3  5
> 10: 4  6  3  6
> 11: 6  7  2  6
> 12: 6  7  2  7
> 13: 8  8  1  8
> 14: 1 10 10  1
> 15: 1 10 10  2
> 16: 1 10 10  3
> 17: 1 10 10  4
> 18: 1 10 10  5
> 19: 1 10 10  6
> 20: 1 10 10  7
> 21: 1 10 10  8
> 22: 1 10 10  9
> 23: 1 10 10 10
>     A  B  C  D
> ```

**Note** You can easily change `K` within `seq`, i.e.

```
setDT(d1)[, C := B - A + 1][, 
     D := list(list(seq(A, B, by = 0.2))), by = 1:nrow(d1)][, 
                lapply(.SD, unlist), by = 1:nrow(d1)][, 
                                              nrow := NULL][]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use lists and `purr` package to process each row of your data frame:

```
data.frame(A=c(2,4,6,8,1),B=c(8,6,7,8,10)) %>%   # take original data frame
  setNames(c("from", "to")) %>% pmap(seq) %>%    # sequence from A to B
  map(as_data_frame) %>%                         # convert each element to data frame
  map(~mutate(.,A=min(value), B=max(value))) %>% # add A and B columns
  bind_rows() %>% select(A,B,value)              # combine and reorder columns
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` option where we get the `times` of replication of each row by subtracting the 'B' with 'A' column ('i1'), create that as column 'C', then replicate the sequence of rows of original dataset using 'i1'.  Finally, the 'D' column is created by getting the sequence of corresponding elements of 'A' and 'B' using `Map`.  The output will be a `list`, so we `unlist` it to make a `vector`

```
i1 <- with(d1, B - A + 1) 
d1$C <- i1
d2 <- d1[rep(seq_len(nrow(d1)), i1),]
d2$D <-  unlist(Map(`:`, d1$A, d1$B))
row.names(d2) <- NULL
d2
#   A  B  C  D
#1  2  8  7  2
#2  2  8  7  3
#3  2  8  7  4
#4  2  8  7  5
#5  2  8  7  6
#6  2  8  7  7
#7  2  8  7  8
#8  4  6  3  4
#9  4  6  3  5
#10 4  6  3  6
#11 6  7  2  6
#12 6  7  2  7
#13 8  8  1  8
#14 1 10 10  1
#15 1 10 10  2
#16 1 10 10  3
#17 1 10 10  4
#18 1 10 10  5
#19 1 10 10  6
#20 1 10 10  7
#21 1 10 10  8
#22 1 10 10  9
#23 1 10 10 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple example using N (case where k = 1)

```
library(dplyr)

# example data frame
d1 <- data.frame(A=c(2,4,6,8,1),B=c(8,6,7,8,10))

# function to use (must have same column names)
f = function(d) {
  A = rep(d$A, d$diff)
  B = rep(d$B, d$diff)
  C = seq(d$A, d$B)
  data.frame(A, B, C) }


d1 %>%
  mutate(diff = B - A + 1) %>%  # calculate difference
  rowwise() %>%                 # for every row
  do(f(.)) %>%                  # apply the function
  ungroup()                     # forget the grouping

#  # A tibble: 23 x 3
#       A     B     C
# * <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     2     8     2
# 2     2     8     3
# 3     2     8     4
# 4     2     8     5
# 5     2     8     6
# 6     2     8     7
# 7     2     8     8
# 8     4     6     4
# 9     4     6     5
# 10    4     6     6
# # ... with 13 more rows
```

Example where you have one k for all rows (I'm using 0.25 to demonstrate)

```
# example data frame
d1 <- data.frame(A=c(2,4,6,8,1),B=c(8,6,7,8,10))

# function to use (must have same column names)
f = function(d, k) {
  A = d$A
  B = d$B
  C = seq(d$A, d$B, k)
  data.frame(A, B, C) }


d1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%       # for every row
  do(f(., 0.25)) %>%   # apply the function using your own k
  ungroup()   

#  # A tibble: 77 x 3
#       A     B     C
# * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2     8  2.00
# 2     2     8  2.25
# 3     2     8  2.50
# 4     2     8  2.75
# 5     2     8  3.00
# 6     2     8  3.25
# 7     2     8  3.50
# 8     2     8  3.75
# 9     2     8  4.00
# 10    2     8  4.25
# # ... with 67 more rows
```

Example where you have different k for each row

```
# example data frame
# give manually different k for each row
d1 <- data.frame(A=c(2,4,6,8,1),B=c(8,6,7,8,10))
d1$k = c(0.5, 1, 2, 0.25, 1.5)

d1

#   A  B    k
# 1 2  8 0.50
# 2 4  6 1.00
# 3 6  7 2.00
# 4 8  8 0.25
# 5 1 10 1.50


# function to use (must have same column names)
f = function(d) {
  A = d$A
  B = d$B
  C = seq(d$A, d$B, d$k)
  data.frame(A, B, C) }


d1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%   # for every row
  do(f(.)) %>%    # apply the function using different k for each row
  ungroup() 

#  # A tibble: 25 x 3
#       A     B     C
# * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2     8   2.0
# 2     2     8   2.5
# 3     2     8   3.0
# 4     2     8   3.5
# 5     2     8   4.0
# 6     2     8   4.5
# 7     2     8   5.0
# 8     2     8   5.5
# 9     2     8   6.0
# 10    2     8   6.5
# # ... with 15 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It helps me a lot.  Here I have a small question, If **K** is 0.02, then how can we do it?

Comment: So, K = 0.02 will be the step in your sequence? And you expect to see it in column C in this example, like 2, 2.02, 2.04, ..... , 8 ? Then how is this going to affect N which is the difference and equal to 7? Can you give me an example? I feel that K has to be one because every time you create N rows and there's no more space to store a sequence with more elements.

Comment: Hi Antoniosk, When I change my step(**k**) value, **N** value also changes. In the above example, if we change **k**=0.02  then  **N** becomes 301. To achieve this goal, we need to make change in the above code as `setDT(d1)[, C := (B - A)*(1/k) + 1]`

Comment: I get it. It was confusing for me the example with the N as the difference of the two numbers. You could say that's the case when K = 1. I'll update my answer to deal with a) a universal k input, b) different k input for each row.